# What is the best way to manage access logs for each user?

Tags: algorithm, logging

I want to know the history the user logged into the service.
I simply want to see how often users are logged in on a daily, weekly and monthly basis.

Currently, user ID and connection time are stored in DB table.

Too long lines unnecessarily.

If there is another good way, please refer to it.

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Too long lines unnecessarily.'? Using a DB sounds reasonable.

Comment: @whdals0 : so you need average values for logins per day, week and month, right?

Comment: @MrSmith42 Data is stacked in N * 3 form. (seq, userid, time). I wonder if there is a more efficient way.

Comment: @GregorOphey Not average. I want to check login data per user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution in a hypthetical language:

You would have to keep two data items per user:

```
TimeStamp firstLoginOf(user_id) : returns time stamp of first login for given user
Integer totalLoginsOf(user_id)  : returns total number of logins for given user
```

The data has to be stored in a file or DB indexed by user_id.
The total number of logins is incremented whenever the corresponding user logs in.

Then you can compute the desired data as follows:

```
Float loginsPerDay(user_id) {
    return totalLoginsOf(user_id) / asDays( now() - firstLoginOf(user_id) )
}

Float loginsPerWeek(user_id) {
    return totalLoginsOf(user_id) / asWeeks( now() - firstLoginOf(user_id) )
}

Float loginsPerMonth(user_id) {
    return totalLoginsOf(user_id) / asMonths( now() - firstLoginOf(user_id) )
}
```

Comment: Oh, I think, your method is awesome. Thanks Gregor.